# Second card in memory wont turn face up

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to do a memory game and have a slight problem when i want to turn two cards up to be displayed for the player.

The thing that happen when i run my memory game is that the first cards displays correctly but when i click on the second card it keeps being face down unless it's a pair.

```
if (model.getCard(tile.getNr()).getCardState() == CardState.DOWN) {
                model.getCard(tile.getNr()).setCardState(CardState.UP);
                tile.setImg(model.getCard(tile.getNr()).getValue()); //sets the correct image onto the card
                click--;
                //test if equal
                if (click == 0) {
                    for (Cards card1 : cards) {
                        if (card1.getCardState() == CardState.UP) {
                            if (tile.getNr() != cards.indexOf(card1)) {
                                if (model.getCard(tile.getNr()).getValue() == card1.getValue()) {
                                    //if both cards are equal, set them both to paired
                                    model.getCard(tile.getNr()).setCardState(CardState.PAIRED);
                                    model.getCard(cards.indexOf(card1)).setCardState(CardState.PAIRED);
                                    click = 2;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);                 //1000 milliseconds is one second.
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                    }
                    for (Cards card1 : cards) {
                        if (card1.getCardState() != CardState.PAIRED && card1.getCardState() == CardState.UP) {
                            model.getCard(cards.indexOf(card1)).setCardState(CardState.DOWN);
                            tiles.get(cards.indexOf(card1)).setCardDown();
                        }
                    }
                    click = 2;
                }
            }
```

I have the delay so the player can see both of the cards before they turn over.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Thread.sleep(500);` you block the application thread preventing the UI from updating. You need to wait in a way that allows the application thread to continue, e.g. using [`PauseTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PauseTransition.html).

```
if (click == 0) {
    ... turn card face up ...

    PauseTransition transition = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(500));
    transition.setOnFinished(evt -> {
        ... turn cards face down ...
    });
    transition.play();
}
```